# Canonical dupe for mucking after an all-in?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

This question [All in player mucks hand before runout](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/11695/3816) was recently posted regarding mucking a hand before the river in an all-in situation.

I started to answer it but then noticed there are several other similar questions, only one of which has an accepted answer.

[Mucking a winning hand](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/5751/3816) (1) has an accepted answer, but it doesn't fully cover tournament vs cash game rulings.

Other questions include:

- [Muck before river](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/8877/3816) regarding an all-in with three players
- [Must the initial all-in raiser, that got called, show (or muck) BEFORE the river?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/9138/3816) also about an all-in with three players
- [Mucking cards on an all-in hand](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/10311/3816) very similar to the original question with two good answers, covering both cash and tournament situations, but neither accepted.

Should they all be marked as dupes of (1), possibly with an edit to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave them a quick read. The actions in the hands/questions presented are obviously very similar, though with the added narrative can appear different. This might add a little nuance to the situation so I'm not particularly inclined to close/consolidate any of them right now. I suppose from a technical perspective, and if someone gave a thorough answer, you could certainly consolidate at least two of these questions. That said, people find this site in a whole lot of different ways; One persons keyword trash are another's keyword gold!

I don't think we're in dire need of consolidating the questions & answers just yet but I can wholeheartedly see your point Herb. What would be your preferred option?

Comment: When I posted this, I thought that there should be one question selected as the dupe target, but the more I think about it, the more I agree they should be left alone, at least for now.